# Luabind objects disapearing when I enter a new file

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I'm using [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) to bind my Lua scripts to my C++ engine. (it uses lua 5.1.4)

I added a new lua script called "controller.lua" which my entities script, called "cat.lua", will reference and use. One the c++ calls the method "Update" it's all in the hands of Lua.

But once I try to pass my binded c++ methods to the new script file, it feels like all the bindings from that c++ object disapear. I get the following error:

Expression: scripts/controller.lua:5(method MoveUp)
scripts/controller.lua:5: attempt to call method 'GetComponent' (a nil value)

Here is some C++ snippets

```
// Definitions
module(luaState)
[
    class_<Entity>("Entity")
        .def("GetComponent", &Entity::GetComponent)
    class_<Component>("Component")
        .enum_("eComponentTypes")
        [
            value("Steering", kComponentType_Steering)
        ],
    class_<SteeringComponent>("SteeringComponent")
];

// The script components update
void ScriptComponent::Update() {
    const Entity* owner = this.GetOwner();
    mLuaDataTable["Update"](owner); // Executes the Update function on the script Cat.lua
}
```

The entities code being called by c++ (When it executes it returns the Cat table to c++.)

```
-- Cat.lua
local controller = loadfile("scripts/controller.lua")
local Cat = {}

function Cat.Update(entity)
    steeringComponent = entity:GetComponent(Component.Steering) -- Works fine
    controller:MoveUp(entity)
end

return Cat
```

and the Controller

```
--controller.lua
local up = vec2(0.0, 1.0)
local Controller = {}

function Controller.MoveUp(entity)
    steeringComponent = entity:GetComponent(Component.Steering) -- Fails
end

return Controller
```

Bonus points:
When I make a change to the controller that doesn't work (like if I just threw an s character anywhere), the controller loads up nil, no warnings. Is there some way to make it throw warnings?

Is there a better way I should be doing to "link" to other lua files, like the way im working with Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ToxicFrog on Freenode chat for helping me figure this one out.

Basically: I was calling controller MoveUp like so:

```
controller:MoveUp(entity)
```

which of course translates into

```
controller.MoveUp(controller, entity)
```

and the function was defined as

```
function Controller.MoveUp(entity)
```

this "entity" was accepted as the first parameter, controller, while the actual entity is discarded per spec.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial